# 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement' vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have this SQL statement however despite using INSERT INTO statements i don't understand why this statement isn't working. The error is 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement' And the statement is:

```
"INSERT INTO LoginInformation (Username, Password) VALUES ('" & HashedUsername 
 & "', '" & HashedPassword & "')"
```

Just wondering if anyone can see any obvious errors. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  That will probably fix the syntax error.

Comment: There’s no reason to be creating queries dynamically. Look up “parameterized queries”.

Comment: Also research the keywords and reserved words for the DB provider you are using (you didnt mention it).  Very likely `password` is a reserved word.  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix it was the keywords

Comment: Glad to help.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]